# Displaying Dynamic Data using Sysdate - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to return the fNo column results to all data even when the data in a column is null?

Current Code:

```
Select a.sNo, a.tCode, a.fno
from airplane a, Scheduled_Flight s
Where a.fno = s.fno or SDT >= trunc(sysdate);
```

Example Output from Oracle SQL:

```
SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           VA82723

SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330
0000002 A320                           VA12190

SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000006 A330                           VA82123
```

I only want to display results in the flight number (fNo) column for flights which are scheduled for today. Other flights, which are not scheduled for today, should return a null value in the fno column, whilst still listing all flights. Any help would much be appreciated as I am new to SQL.

EDIT: 
This is the output when removing  `WHERE SDT >= TRUNC (SYSDATE);`
I would like to show all the sNo like below but only the fNo of sno 0000003 and 0000005. Not the other flights which are not scheduled for today.

```
SQL> SELECT a.sNo, a.tCode, a.fno
  2    FROM airplane a LEFT OUTER JOIN Scheduled_Flight s ON a.fno = s.fno;

SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330

7 rows selected.
```

EDIT 2:

```
 SELECT a.sNo, a.tCode, a.fno
  2    FROM airplane a LEFT OUTER JOIN Scheduled_Flight s ON a.fno = s.fno
  3   AND SDT >= TRUNC (SYSDATE)
  4   order by a.sno;

SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330
```

EDIT 3:
I would like to display the following.

```
SNO     TCODE                          FNO
------- ------------------------------ -------
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           
0000003 A330                           VA82716
0000004 A330                           
0000005 A330                           VA82722
0000006 A330                           
0000007 A330
```

EDIT 4: With this can I group by SDT and only show the FNO for the shown SDT's?

```
SNO     TCODE                          FNO     SDT
------- ------------------------------ ------- --------------------
0000001 A320
0000002 A320                           VA12190
0000003 A330                           VA82716 11/SEP/2017 21:59:00
0000004 A330                           VA82723
0000005 A330                           VA82722 11/SEP/2017 14:00:00
0000006 A330                           VA82123
0000007 A330
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.sNo, a.tCode,s.fno
    FROM airplane a LEFT OUTER JOIN Scheduled_Flight s ON a.fno = s.fno
```

Comment: This only returns the flights for today and not the other flights which are not scheduled. For example, the flights which are not scheduled for today need to also be displayed with the fNo being blank/null in the column for these flights.

Comment: So. It means you don't need `SDT >= TRUNC (SYSDATE)` ?

Comment: Check the query now. I have included `AND` instead of `WHERE`

Comment: INSERT INTO scheduled_flight 
            (fno, 
             sdt, 
             sat, 
             dcity, 
             ocity) 
VALUES      ( 'VA82716', 
             '11-sep-2017 21:59', 
             '11-sep-2017 23:30', 
             'Sydney', 
             'Canberra' );

Comment: This is an example of the column for scheduled flights. It should not be displayed in the fno due to the flight being from yesterday, not today.

Comment: Did the previous query not help?

Comment: Please refer to edit 3 to see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can u also add date column into your expected result

Comment: I have figured out how to do it I just needed to change a.fno to s.fno hahaha